# VBA won't input formula on range

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a macro where I want it to apply a formula to some cells. For the R1C1 formula to be right I recorded only the formula.
When I went to test it I got the error 1004, but there's a range selected, so I'm not sure what's wrong...

If someone could please help me, I'm quite stuck. Thanks!

```
UltLinhaBD = Cells(800, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For LinhaAba = 2 To UltLinhaBD

            If Cells(LinhaAba, 1) <> "" Then
                Cells(LinhaAba, 20) = _
                    "=IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R6C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C3),(-RC16*'Premissas Financeiras'!R6C3)," & Chr(10) & "IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R7C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C3),(-RC16*'Premissas Financeiras'!R7C3)," & Chr(10) & "IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R6C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C4),(-RC16*'Premissas Financ" & _
                    "6C4)," & Chr(10) & "IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R7C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C4),(-RC16*'Premissas Financeiras'!R7C4)," & Chr(10) & "IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R6C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C5),(-RC16*'Premissas Financeiras'!R6C5)," & Chr(10) & "IF(AND(RC5=Infos!R2C4,RC9='Premissas Financeiras'!R7C2,RC3='Premissas Financeiras'!R2C5),(-RC16*'Premissas F" & _
                    "s'!R7C5),))))))"
                Cells(LinhaAba, 22) = "=-RC[-2]*RC[-1]"
                Cells(LinhaAba, 4) = "Dedução"
            End If

        Next LinhaAba
```

The formula itself is:

```
=IF(AND($E3=Infos!$D$2;$I3='Premissas Financeiras'!$B$6;$C3='Premissas Financeiras'!$C$2);(-$P3*'Premissas Financeiras'!$C$6); IF(AND($E3=Infos!$D$2;$I3='Premissas Financeiras'!$B$7;$C3='Premissas Financeiras'!$C$2);(-$P3*'Premissas Financeiras'!$C$7); IF(AND($E3=Infos!$D$2;$I3='Premissas Financeiras'!$B$6;$C3='Premissas Financeiras'!$D$2);(-$P3*'Premissas Financeiras'!$D$6); IF(AND($E3=Infos!$D$2;$I3='Premissas Financeiras'!$B$7;$C3='Premissas Financeiras'!$D$2);(-$P3*'Premissas Financeiras'!$D$7); IF(AND($E3=Infos!$D$2;$I3='Premissas Financeiras'!$B$6;$C3='Premissas Financeiras'!$E$2);(-$P3*'Premissas Financeiras'!$E$6); IF(AND($E3=Infos!$D$2;$I3='Premissas Financeiras'!$B$7;$C3='Premissas Financeiras'!$E$2);(-$P3*'Premissas Financeiras'!$E$7);))))))
```

I used the macro recorder to convert it into vba, since I don't really know how to use the .FormulaR1C1 notation well.

The full sub is:

```
Sub Deduções()

Dim Aba As String
Dim iCounter As Long
Dim Coluna As Long
Dim Linha As Long
Dim ColAba As Long
Dim LinhaAba As Long
Dim UltLinhaAba As Long
Dim UltLinhaBD As Long

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range

Dim Iniciativa As String
Dim Tipo As String
Dim Ano As Long


' Deduções

' Inserir função que multiplica total da receita à premissa de dedução e função que multiplica valor unitário pela qtde
    Sheets("Deduções").Select

        Range("T2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*'Premissas Financeiras'!R7C3"
        Range("T2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("T2:T7"), Type:=xlFillDefault


        UltLinhaBD = Cells(800, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For LinhaAba = 2 To UltLinhaBD

            If Cells(LinhaAba, 1) <> "" Then
                Cells(LinhaAba, 20) = "=RC[-4]*'Premissas Financeiras'!R7C3"
                Cells(LinhaAba, 22) = "=-RC[-2]*RC[-1]"
                Cells(LinhaAba, 4) = "Dedução"
            End If

        Next LinhaAba

' Colar quantidade
    Columns("Q:Q").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("U:U").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

' Colar valor
    Columns("T:V").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

' Deletar colunas indesejadas
    Columns("P:S").Select
    Selection.Delete

    UltLinhaBD = Cells(500, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For LinAba = 2 To UltLinhaBD

        If Cells(LinAba, 1).Value = "INICIATIVA" Then
            Cells(LinAba, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    Next LinAba

' Cabeçalho

    Cells(1, 1).Value = "INICIATIVA"
    Cells(1, 2).Value = "TIPO"
    Cells(1, 3).Value = "ANO"
    Cells(1, 4).Value = "R/D"
    Cells(1, 5).Value = "AGRUPAMENTO"
    Cells(1, 6).Value = "ETAPA"
    Cells(1, 7).Value = "CAT 3"
    Cells(1, 8).Value = "CAT 4"
    Cells(1, 9).Value = "CAT 5"
    Cells(1, 10).Value = "CAT 6"
    Cells(1, 11).Value = "DETALHAMENTO"
    Cells(1, 12).Value = "EMPRESA"
    Cells(1, 13).Value = "CONTRIBUIÇÃO"
    Cells(1, 14).Value = "UNIDADE"
    Cells(1, 15).Value = "VISÃO"
    Cells(1, 16).Value = "VALOR UNITÁRIO"
    Cells(1, 17).Value = "QUANTIDADE"
    Cells(1, 18).Value = "TOTAL"
    Cells(1, 19).Value = "OBS"


Sheets("Deduções").Select

    Set rng1 = Cells.Find("*", [a1], xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Set rng2 = Cells.Find("*", [a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng3 = Range([a1], Cells(rng1.Row, rng2.Column))
        'if you need to actual select the range (which is rare in VBA)
        Application.Goto rng3
    Else
        MsgBox "sheet is blank", vbCritical
    End If

    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("BD").Select
    Range("A900").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you writting `**` and you need to insert formulas like this: `Cells(LinhaAba, 20).FormulaR1C1 = "=YOURFORMULA"`

Comment: I didn't put the **, they aren't appearing in the code on the VBA

Comment: `Cells(row, column) = 42` is assigning to *the value*, not the *formula* (the `=` probably makes it the formula, but that doesn't default to R1C1 AFAIK). That said you have `RC[...]` notation in one place, and `R2C4,RC9` in the other. `RC5` looks like a valid A1-style cell reference. So, fix the R1C1 notation and assign to `.FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: Why do you have `CHR(10)` in the *formula*?

Comment: I didn't write the formula on VBA, I wrote it directly on my cell and recorded the macro so it converted it to code... I'm not sure why there's Chr(10).

I'll edit my question to include the formula itself, without coding